# Leibniz rule when range of integration is defined by inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, contour-integration

I would like to solve this

$$\frac{\partial\int_{S(x)>S(\theta)}(S(x)-S(\theta))dF(x)}{\partial\theta}$$

where $S$ is a single-valued, differentiable, and strictly increasing function and $F$ is a distribution function.

This is more advanced than the Leibniz rule explained in wikipedia or any page that comes up easily. In those pages, range of integration is defined easily as interval.

More generally, I want to solve when there are more than 1 variable, but differentiation is taken by one variable:

$$\frac{\partial\int_{S(x_{1},x_{2})>S(\theta_{1},\theta_{2})}(S(x_{1},x_{2})-S(\theta_{1},\theta_{2}))dF(x_{1},x_{2})}{\partial\theta_{1}}$$

Does it need to be zero? At least that should be what I will be getting to be consistent with the paper I am reading. I tried to apply the concept in the Leibniz rule as it is defined online but it doesn't seem to be straightforward.

Comment: How are $S$ and $F$ defined?

Comment: @MattSamuel  S is a function. F is a distribution function. So its derivative will be `f`

Comment: I can choose $S$ that will make the formula nonsense because the derivative will not exist. So you need to be more specific about the function.

Comment: @MattSamuel  Thank you. It is single-valued, differentiable, and strictly increasing.

Comment: Then the integral is over the interval $[\theta, \infty) $, isn't it?

Comment: if $S$ is strictly increasing then $S(x)>S(\theta)\iff x>\theta$, and so $$\int_{S(x)>S(\theta)}\cdots dx=\int_\theta^\infty\cdots dx$$

Comment: @Masacroso   Yes. How does that apply to multi-variate case?

Comment: In any case, isn't it impossible for the second (multivariate case) differentiation to be zero?  $S(x_{1},x_{2})-S(\theta_{1},\theta_{2})$   decreases, and the range also decreases with $\theta_{1}$

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Higher_dimensions)

Comment: @Masacroso  Yes I took a look at that but it's written in language of physics so I couldn't understand what they are talking.

Comment: What do you think about my reasoning that it really can't be zero?

Comment: @user42459 it is not language of physics only, continue reading: it is explicitly stated in terms of Lie derivatives and differential geometry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87891/discussion-between-user42459-and-masacroso).